# Logistic Regression: Train using past data and predict using current data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've trained and tested my logistic regression using available data but now need to output a future prediction. I want to include the 2017 values that I used in my training and test set to predict the 2018 probability.

This is the code I used to train and test my model:

```
Xadj = train.ix[:,('2016 transaction count','critical_CI', 'critical_CN','critical_CS', 
  'critical_FI', 'critical_IN','critical_OI','critical_RA','create_year_2012', 'create_year_2013', 
      'create_year_2014', 'create_year_2015','create_year_2016')]

#Coded is the transformation of 2017 transaction count to a binary variable
y = y=train.ix[:,('2017 transaction count coded')] 

logit_model=sm.Logit(y,Xadj)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xadj, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
print('Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(X_test, y_test)))

#Cross Validation
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
modelCV = LogisticRegression()
scoring = 'accuracy'
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(modelCV, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print("10-fold cross validation average accuracy: %.3f" % (results.mean()))
```

In an attempt to export predictions for 2018, I have done the following:

```
#Create 2018 Purchase Probability
train['2018 Purchase Probability']=pd.DataFrame({'2018 Purchase Probability' : []})

yact=train.ix[:,('2018 Purchase Probability')]
#Adding in 2017 values
X = train.ix[:, ('2017 transaction count','critical_CI', 'critical_CN','critical_CS', 
  'critical_FI', 'critical_IN','critical_OI','critical_RA','create_year_2012', 'create_year_2013', 
      'create_year_2014', 'create_year_2015','create_year_2016','create_year_2017')]

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale, StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(Xadj)
X = scaler.transform(Xadj)
X_pred = scaler.transform(X)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(Xadj, y)

#Generate 0/1 prediction
prediction = logreg.predict(X= X)

#Generate odds ratio
precent_prediction = logreg.predict_proba(X= X)

prediction = pd.DataFrame(prediction)
```

I'm not sure if I've done this correctly and judging from my output (which is mostly 1's) I don't think I have. I am new to coding in Python and am struggling to turn my tested model into a future prediction that  can be used to make decisions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you please explain clearly what you are doing? You are using 2016 data as features and 2017 transaction count as target and training the model. Now you dont have 2018 transaction count and want to predict that, so why are you training the model again? And whats `y` in this case?

Comment: @VivekKumar, I am using 2016 features to predict whether we will purchase again in 2017. Having identified which features are of use, I am now wanting to predict whether we will purchase an item again in 2018, using the actual 2017 transaction count.

This is likely a simple issue with my coding. I have attempted to replace 2016 transaction count with 2017 transaction count as a feature and 2017 transaction binary variable (1 for purchased, 0 for not purchased) with an empty column, 2018 Purchase Probability. This has resulted in an output that can't be correct.

Comment: yact is my desired y variable for the final model but when I use the below line of code I receive an error:

    logit_model=sm.Logit(yact,X)
    result=logit_model.fit()
    print(result.summary())

ValueError: endog must be in the unit interval. on the line logit_model=sm.Logit(yact,X)

If I comment this out and use this code I receive this error:
    logreg = LogisticRegression()
    logreg.fit(Xadj, yact)

Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). referring to the line 
     logreg.fit(Xadj, yact)